How to detect if a route exit was triggered by browser back button or context.go in Flutter using GoRouter and StatefulShell?
I'm working on a Flutter web project using GoRouter with a StatefulShell for route management. I want to differentiate between route exits triggered by the browser's back button and programmatic navigation using context.go.
In my onExit and redirect methods for a route, I need to handle these two scenarios differently.
How can I detect if the route exit was caused by the user hitting the browser's back button, or if it was triggered by my code using context.go()?
Here's an example of how I'm using GoRouter and StatefulShell:
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

// private navigators
final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _shellNavigatorMainPageKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'main');
final _shellNavigatorSettingsPageKey =
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: 'settings');

final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  redirect: (context, state) {
    log(
      'here check if we pressed browser back button or changing the page from the navigator rails',
    );
    return null;
  },
  routes: [
    StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
      builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
        // the UI shell
        return HomePage(navigationShell: navigationShell);
      },
      branches: [
        StatefulShellBranch(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorMainPageKey,
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/',
              onExit: (context, state) {
                log(
                  'here check if we pressed browser back button or changing the page from the navigator rails',
                );
                return true;
              },
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
                child: MainPage(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        // second branch (B)
        StatefulShellBranch(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorSettingsPageKey,
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/settings',
              onExit: (context, state) {
                log(
                  'here check if we pressed browser back button or changing the page from the navigator rails',
                );
                return true;
              },
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
                child: SettingsPage(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _router.routerDelegate.addListener(
      () {},
    );
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell;

  const HomePage({
    super.key,
    required this.navigationShell,
  });

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          NavigationRail(
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
              if (index == 0) {
                context.go('/');
              } else if (index == 1) {
                context.go('/settings');
              }
            },
            labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.selected,
            destinations: const <NavigationRailDestination>[
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                ),
                label: Text('Main'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.settings,
                ),
                label: Text('Settings'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const VerticalDivider(thickness: 1, width: 2),
          Expanded(
            child: widget.navigationShell,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'main page',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Setting page',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}




You can use listeners
_router.routerDelegate.addListener(_onRouteChanged);

and detect it inside stream
refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(
        Stream.fromFuture(Future.microtask(() => null)),
      ),

Example code
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _router = GoRouter(
      initialLocation: '/home',
      routes: [
        GoRoute(path: '/home', builder: (context, state) => HomePage()),
        GoRoute(path: '/settings', builder: (context, state) => SettingsPage()),
      ],
      // This listens to any route change
      refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(
        Stream.fromFuture(Future.microtask(() => null)),
      ),
    );

    _router.routerDelegate.addListener(_onRouteChanged);
  }

  void _onRouteChanged() {
    if (_isContextGoTriggered) {
      // Route was changed by context.go
      debugPrint('Route changed by context.go');
      _isContextGoTriggered = false; // Reset the flag
    } else {
      // Route was changed by browser back button
      debugPrint('Route changed by browser back button');
    }
  }

Try this

can you add simple code example

edited the answer please have a look

Where did you import GoRouterRefreshStream from?

They changed it check this here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/108128
